# Best options to display a popup for angularjs app based on conditions

Tags: angularjs, cookies, local-storage

I have an angularjs app with ASP.NET WebAPI2 REST APIs. There is a scenario where I have a display a popup for initiating a survey for end users (both authenticated and anonymous types). On clicking the popup options, the user will be redirected to another applicaiton which captures all the responses provided by the user.

There is no relation between the angularjs app and the survey application.

Now next time if the user revisits the application then in that case based on the previous action taken to fill the survey , I have to take a decision to display or hide the popup for the user.

I thought of cookies and localStorage as the options but I think are not ideal choices for this scenario.

Can anyone help me to know are there any other possible options to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using the redirection link.
For example if he finished correctly the Survey you will redirect him to:
www.myapp.com/survey/success
Than in the App you can do something like: get the URL parameters, if the parameters is success store it on localStorage so next time he revisits the web-page the Popup wont show.

Otherwise direct him to:
www.myapp.com/survey/

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option here is to save this information in the database using your  ASP.NET WebAPI2 REST APIs. In the moment that the end user clicks the survey you can also make an Api call which will save in the database info about user's action(this will probably be sth you can do for authenticated users). For not authenticated users you can just save that information in localStorage in the moment they are clicking the survey.

Comment: Thanks  Whatives for your response. It is possible that the user may delete the localStorage. How to handle the scenario. Any inputs on this is much appreciated.